# How to assign a tuple to a namedtuple?

Tags: python, namedtuple

A simple question: I have a namedtuple like so

```
RowSource = namedtuple("RowSource","parcel_id str_number pre_direct prefix street_name ...")
```

In total there are 16 names. And I have a tuple of length 16 I want to assign to the named tuple

```
t = (653,
526011,
'950',
None,
None,
'county road 999',
None,
None,
'tule',
'ca',
96134,
9225,
-121.400979,
41.877468,
'0101000020E610000080D8D2A3A9595EC0ADA415DF50F04440',
'0101000020E610000080D8D2A3A9595EC0ADA415DF50F04440')
```

What is the easiest way to do this? I mean, I don't go and do t[0],t[1] etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `*args` syntax to apply each item in `t` as a separate argument:

```
RowSource(*t)
```

Alternatively, use the [`namedtuple._make()` class method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._make):

```
RowSource._make(t)
```

The latter has a slightly more helpful `TypeError` exception message:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> SampleTuple = namedtuple('Sample', 'foo bar baz')
>>> SampleTuple(1, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
>>> SampleTuple._make((1, 2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 17, in _make
TypeError: Expected 3 arguments, got 2
```

The `__new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)` text while you clearly passed in only 2 throws some newer users of Python off, the `namedtuple_make()` class method is slightly more informative here.

Comment: Great, very helpful as always. Thanks.

Comment: Any function on an object with an underscore at the beginning should be avoided because they are generally recognized as private functions in Python. I'd suggest using what Martijn first suggested.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: `namedtuple` uses underscore methods to avoid limiting the names you can use, not to make them private. `namedtuple._make()` is public, but not called `make` so you can create a named tuple with `make` as one of the positional entries.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But is it not a general convention to put an underscore for a private function? Why has `namedtuple` ignored that convention in this case? And how does not using an underscore limit the names you can use?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: Because each entry in a named tuple is also an attribute. The namedtuple in this answer has the attributes `foo`, `bar` and `baz`, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ahh, I forgot about that bit. But, I think thats because I'm confusing `namedtuple` with the factory design pattern. But `namedtuple` is actually sub-classing the type that we are creating.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: If the methods on a `namedtuple` did *not* use leading underscores, I could not use the names `make`, `asdict`, `fields` and `replace`; `namedtuple('Example', 'make asdict replace fields')` would clash with the methods on the class.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yea, I looked that up in the docs right now. Unfortunately, the underscore rule was hardwired in my brain :P

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be this:

```
RowSource(*t)
```